# Configuration Variables and Sequelizer

Tags: appharbor

I'm creating a WCF service on AppHarbor and trying to leverage the configuration variables for my SQL connection. I closely followed the description on http://support.appharbor.com/kb/add-ons/using-sequelizer but the deployed web.config still contains the same connectionString info as my local machine.

1. I set the SQLSERVER_CONNECTION_STRING_ALIAS to the value "SQLSERVER_CONNECTION_STRING"
2. My web.config contains these elements:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="SQLSERVER_CONNECTION_STRING"
   connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;  Initial Catalog=MyCoolName; Integrated Security=SSPI;"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

1. the solution works correctly on my machine.
2. the solution deploys to AppHarbor without any errors or warnings.
3. I created a WCF service that displays the connection string. It returns my local SQLEXPRESS connectionString, not the AppHarbor sequelizer connectionString.

Why won't AppHarbor replace the value of the connectionString in my web.config after the solution is deployed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't work if you call it `SQLSERVER_CONNECTION_STRING` (due to the mechanics of how we replace values), call it `shawnsappsconnectionstring` or something like that instead and specify that as the alias on Sequelizer.

I'll add a note in the docs.

Comment: That took care of it right away. The importance of being original. :)